# Spawning Honey bees

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So honey bees can only appear in non-freezing zones and in some cases not at all.. 
I embarked onto a prime location but found it utterly devoid of any vermin nests despite it being a warm climate :(

After much googling I can't find any solution for creating hives on the map.  I can use the spawnunit dfhack script to create honey bees like so:

spawnunit HONEY_BEE WORKER

But these do not nest they just fly around, fighting each other until none remain.
And tiletypes doesn't seem to have the answer either as VERMIN is not listed a material, special, or variant tile.

Comment: Even if bees are not present when embarking, they might spawn later on all by themselves. I have no clue about the preconditions however. Also, if it is possible, you might need to spawn the hive itself, which is probably not a creature/unit. I would guess they are handled similar to plants. Maybe a multi-file search to the term "hive" to find the exact entity would be helpful? Also the last time I played, hivekeeping was not really working, but there have been a number of releases in the mean time

Comment: Thanks - I know it works from another fort, I am hoping hives start showing up but I am doubtful.  From what I can tell in the files the tile is meant to be VERMIN_SOIL_COLONY but I don't know how to set that

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot answer this either. Maybe there is someone else knowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a dfhack script specifically for this while browsing the github repo!
https://github.com/DFHack/scripts/blob/master/colonies.lua

No idea no one has mentioned this before as the beekeeping industry is so much fun - but this script will simply ADD a honey hive under the cursor and is perfect.

Only problem is its the same name as the colonies plugin so in order to use it in dfhack I renamed hack/scripts/colonies.lua to bees.lua then the command is simply

```
bees place
```